# Lapply changing class of input

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to use the `R0` package to do some COVID-related analysis, but am running into an issue where identical data types are being interpreted as different, and thus am being thrown an error.

```
# load libraries
library(R0) 

# sample data
epid_curve <- sample(1:100, 60, replace = T)

## model that to obtain R0 on day 27 of epidemic
est.R0.EG(epid = epid_curve, 
          GT = generation.time(type = "lognormal", val = c(4.7, 2.9)), 
          begin = 1, 
          end = 27)
```

In the example above, I am manually inputting start and end points into the function and it runs fine. The output is R0, or transmissibility rate, of the disease on day 27. However, what I would like to do is see how R0 changes over the course of the epidemic. Thus, I want to capture R0 on day 2...x.

To me, this seemed fairly straight-forward: use lapply to input different values into the 'end' parameter, save each model in a list, and extract coefficients as needed. However, for whatever reason, when I do this, the function is telling me that the class of begin day and end day are different, even though they are the same:

```
## model that doesn't work
model_day <- lapply(2:length(epid_curve), function(x) {
  model <- est.R0.EG(epid = epid_curve, 
                     GT = generation.time(type = "lognormal", val = c(4.7, 2.9)), 
                     begin = 1, 
                     end = x)
  return(model)
})
```

I have tried wrapping the begin and end parameters in `as.numeric`, `as.integer`, etc. and cannot get it to run for the life of me. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(E0)
set.seed(3)
epid_curve <- sample(1:100, 60, replace = T)
model_day <- lapply(2:length(epid_curve), function(x) {
  model <- est.R0.EG(epid = epid_curve, 
                     GT = generation.time(type = "lognormal", val = c(4.7, 2.9)), 
                     begin = as.integer(1), 
                     end = x)
  return(model)
})
model_day
[[1]]
Reproduction number estimate using  Exponential Growth  method.
R :  540.4266[ 126.3621 , 2551.862 ]


[[2]]
Reproduction number estimate using  Exponential Growth  method.
R :  1.939985[ 0.4389195 , 5.677825 ]
...
```

The trick was in the error message:

```
 Error in integrity.checks(epid, t, GT, begin, end, date.first.obs, time.step,  : 
  If both 'begin'= 1  and 'end'= 2  are provided, they must be of the same class (dates, character strings or integers).
```

You don't have to change `x` because the function `:` returns integer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```r
## model that doesn't work
model_day <- lapply(2:length(epid_curve), function(x) {
  model <- est.R0.EG(epid = epid_curve, 
                     GT = generation.time(type = "lognormal", val = c(4.7, 2.9)), 
                     begin = 1L, 
                     end = x)
  return(model)
})
```

instead. The `1L` casts the `1` as integer.